# How to get json string as response using Webhook in asp.net c# Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, webforms, webhooks

My SMS company have some Webhook method to send the delivery report to our preferred url, then we have to get the data from that url and update it as log.

For this, I am using below code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/sms/response.html") as HttpWebRequest;
        request.UserAgent = "jaidevkh";
        request.ContentType = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml; charset=utf-8";
        request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml";
        request.Method = "GET";
        //request.ContentLength = 0;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        WebHeaderCollection header = response.Headers;
        var encoding = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;
        string responseText = "";
        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
        {
            responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        Label kl = (Label)cph.FindControl("j");
        kl.Text = responseText.ToString();
```

and the json format to come as per SMS vendor in as below:

```
data=[
      {
          "requestId":"35666a716868323535323239",
          "userId":"38229",
          "report":[  
              {  
                  "desc":"REJECTED",
                  "status":"16",
                  "number":"91XXXXXXXXXX",
                  "date":"2015-06-10 17:09:32.0"
              }
          ],
          "senderId":"tester"
      },
      {  
          "requestId":"35666a716868323535323239",
          "userId":"38229",
          "report":[  
              {  
                  "desc":"REJECTED",
                  "status":"16",
                  "number":"91XXXXXXXXXX",
                  "date":"2015-06-10 17:09:32.0"
              },
              {  
                  "desc":"REJECTED",
                  "status":"16",
                  "number":"91XXXXXXXXXX",
                  "date":"2015-06-10 17:09:32.0"
              }
          ],
          "senderId":"tester"
      }
  ]
```

here, this gives responseText as blank. Please suggest what is wrong with this code.

Thanks

Jay

Comment: I don't get it why you create WebRequest to read response? you said the company send the delivery report to our preferred url, So you can get the data in your url instead webrequest.Am i right?

Comment: Might be, but I am confused. Even the code was sent by them as sample. I just modified it per needs.

Comment: when they send any data with any format you can get it and modified it.
for example they send a json result to your url, and the web server parse they request (opening the page with parametr), after that you can modify data and save it.

Comment: Can you show me some example code?

Comment: sure, but let see your json format

Comment: I have added json format in the question itself

Comment: @MahdiFarhani we are still waiting for your comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example for receiveing data from your vendor.

firstly you have to create two models for getting data by vendor format :

```
public class Response
    {
        public string RequestId { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public List<ResponseReport> Report { get; set; }
        public string SenderId { get; set; }
    }

    public class ResponseReport
    {
        public string Desc { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    }
```

*those model is created by your json format*

after that you have to create a handler for getting data (preferred url).

```
public class GetDelivery : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {


            var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            var jsonString = string.Empty;

            context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
            using (var inputStream = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
            {
                jsonString = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
            }

            var data = new List<Response>();
            data = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Response>>(jsonString);


            //Modification and Saving Data

            context.Response.Write("OK");

        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

in this handler you can get what the vendor sent to you, and you can modify and save it.

**Note: the data model and json format must be similar to each other**

**Testing Code**

Finally for testing send data by vendor you can use this code :

```
<button id="send" class="CallHandler">Send</button>
    <script>

        $(".CallHandler").click(function () {
            alert('test');
            $.ajax({
                url: "GetDelivery.ashx",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify([
                    { "requestId": "35666a716868323535323239", "userId": "38229", "report": [{ "desc": "REJECTED", "status": "16", "number": "91XXXXXXXXXX", "date": "2015-06-10 17:09:32.0" }], "senderId": "tester" },
                    { "requestId": "35666a716868323535323239", "userId": "38229", "report": [{ "desc": "REJECTED", "status": "16", "number": "91XXXXXXXXXX", "date": "2015-06-10 17:09:32.0" }, { "desc": "REJECTED", "status": "16", "number": "91XXXXXXXXXX", "date": "2015-06-10 17:09:32.0" }], "senderId": "tester" }
                ]),

            });
            return false;
        });


    </script>
```

I hope it satisfy you.

Comment: I need to stringify the data that comes preferred url, please let me know how I can achieve this.

Comment: your preferd url is http://YourWebsite.com/GetDelivery.ashx,and when your vendor sned data to this address in json format the handler process te request and save the data

Comment: { "requestId": "35666a716868323535323239", "userId": "38229", "report": [{ "desc": "REJECTED", "status": "16", "number": "91XXXXXXXXXX", "date": "2015-06-10 17:09:32.0" }], "senderId": "tester" },
                    { "requestId": "35666a716868323535323239", "userId": "38229", "report": [{ "desc": "REJECTED", "status": "16", "number": "91XXXXXXXXXX", "date": "2015-06-10 17:09:32.0" }, { "desc": "REJECTED", "status": "16", "number": "91XXXXXXXXXX", "date": "2015-06-10 17:09:32.0" }], "senderId": "tester" } will be an example, what should I write instead.

Comment: take a look at Testing code in my post, and replace your json data in java script

Comment: I am completely confused, the string that needs to be replaced will be unknown, so what should I replace in place of that. I am new with json/rest and all these things, so if possible you will need to clear me in detail.

Comment: you don't need to replace any thing, the test part just for testing data send and receive. the main part is handler so when the vendor try to send u deliver message post json data to your handler, Got It ?